# Prove that the class $\{A,A\} = \{A\}$ - does the axiom of class construction work in reverse to prove this?

Tags: set-theory, solution-verification, axioms

Taking place in ZFC.

The axiom of class construction (ACC) states that given a statement expressed in the accepted terms of set theory and a collection of elements $x$, there exists a class of elements which satisfies the statement $P(x)$.

I am tasked with proving that the class $\{A, A\}$ is equivalent to just $\{A\}$. My intuition is to say that since each collection above of $A$ are classes that satisfy the statement $P(x)$, they are the same class.

My hang up is that this would seem to require the axiom to imply *every* class can be created from the rules stated in the ACC. ACC says there exists a class to satisfy any statement, but it seems like there is room to say that there exists classes that don't necessarily fulfill a property. Am I misreading the axiom (does it actually imply this and I don't see it?). Generally, am I on the right track for proving this?

Comment: What class theory are you working with?  I'd expect it to have some form of extensionality.

Comment: The axiom of class construction that you describe is not an axiom of ZFC.

Comment: It is according to http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~randre/1aaset_theory_140613.pdf @Vsotvep

Comment: @user7778287 His list of axioms is then not the usual standard. In fact, the class construction axiom is completely irrelevant in his theory: it states that classes exist, but it does not give any power to do constructions on them. The elements that we are interested in are *sets*, which is why all the other axioms only talk about sets. The first axiom can be weakened by replacing "class" with "set", and then you have what most people would consider to be $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Classes in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ are considered a meta-object, that does not actually exist, as far as the theory is concerned.

Comment: Note that there are extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that do use classes as objects, such as Von Neumann-Bernays-Gödel set theory and Morse-Kelley set theory. In these theories you have to take care with extending certain axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ to allow classes, mainly to avoid things like Russell's paradox. These are not topics I would include in an introductory course on set theory, however.

Comment: The best advice I could give you now, is probably to ignore ACC, and consider the mention of classes to be synonymous with the formula that defines them. For example, if $A$ and $B$ are the class of elements defined by $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, then you could read $a\in A$ as an alternative way of writing $\phi(a)$, and you could read $A\subset B$ as $\phi(x)\to\psi(x)$. This is usually how classes are treated in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Most importantly, if you state a formula in the language of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, be sure the formula quantifies over **sets**, and not classes, then you cannot go wrong.

Comment: Apply **Axiom 1** : $x \in \{ A,A \} \leftrightarrow x \in \{ A \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axiom 1 of ZFC, axiom of extent, according to [this book](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~randre/1aaset_theory_140613.pdf) says that if A and B are classes and:

[ $x \in B \leftarrow \rightarrow x \in A$ ]$\leftarrow \rightarrow$ [ $A = B$ ]

So the doubleton *{D, D}*, and the singleton *{D}* can be replaced for $A$ and $B$ in the statement above to show that they are equal according to A1.

Comment: The Axiom of Extensionality of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ says that if $A$ and $B$ are **sets**, then $A=B$ if and only if for all $x$ it holds that $x\in A\leftrightarrow x\in B$. Additionally, the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ do not make any claims about (proper) classes in general, only about *sets*.

Comment: The thing you've written is nonsense: take $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,3\}$, then $A\in B\leftrightarrow B\in A$ is true, but $A\neq B$.

Comment: Class theories like NBG have an axiom of extensionality for classes, but 1) ZFC is not a class theory and 2) what you have written down is by no means the axiom of extensionality.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Please explain why every resource I research lists the axiom of extensibility as the primary rule for ZFC. It seems after the typo was corrected my proof is perfectly valid - though if it isn't your comment has not made clear why.

Comment: @user7778287 It is an axiom of ZFC... not sure how that conflicts with what I said... (read Vsotvep's first comment). Yes, it is correct that they are equal by extensionality, though $\{D\}$ is generally just defined as an abbreviation for $\{D,D\}$ anyway.

Comment: Right, well maybe it is valuable to explain to a novice what class theories are, and what they have to do with the proof in question. I am operating under the axiom provided in below, which (after the correction) the proof can reduce into.

http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~randre/1aaset_theory_140613.pdf

Comment: @user7778287 With the typo corrected, this is indeed the answer. The only $x$ such that $x\in\{D,D\}$ is $x=D$, and similar for $\{D\}$, thus by the axiom of extensionality it follows that $\{D,D\}=\{D\}$.